# How to enable/disable a Button depending on the selection's type in WPF?

Tags: wpf, button, treeview, isenabled

I want to trigger a button's enabled state, according to the type of the current selection.

E.g. I have a treeview that displayes parents and their children. If the selection is on a 'parent' item, the button 'btnShowParentData' is enabled.
I've done this via ValueConvertion:

```
<Button name="btnShowParentData" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=tree, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource ParentSelectedConv}}" />
```

I look for a more elegant way. I don't want to create a ConverterClass for each selection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to create a ConverterClass for each selection type.

You can have properties on the converter to parameterize it.

Comment: With your appraoch: Of what type would be the parameter? A simple string that is compared against typeof(ParentClass).Name?

Comment: Make it a `Type` and compare it directly, in XAML you can easily get `typeof(Class)` using `{x:Type ns:Class}`. (If the property is of type `Type` you don't even need `x:Type`, it gets converted automatically from the string)